# Converting the path of a Rectangle into a GraphicPath/Region

Tags: c#, region, graphicspath

I am learning about `GraphicsPath` and `Region`. And using it with `Invalidate`.

So, I have a `Rectangle` object and I want to erase this rectangle. But, I only want to erase the **edge** of the rectangle (that is, the lines).

At the moment I have this:

```
if(bErase)
{
    Rectangle rcRubberBand = GetSelectionRectangle();

    GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
    path.AddRectangle(rcLastRubberBand);
    Region reg = new Region(path);
    myControl3.Invalidate(reg);
    myControl3.Update();
}
```

It works, but it is invalidating the complete rectangle shape. I only need to invalidate the rectangle **lines** that I had drawn. Can I make such a path with `GraphicsPath`?

Comment: Yes, but it would not help as the system will still only invalidate the bounding rectangle.

Comment: @TaW That is a pity. Ok then I must keep on looking.

Comment: Assuming you meant to save update time. If you just want to restrict the graphics region you can exclude the inner rectangle from the region and use the resulting outline to set the clipping rectangle.

Comment: @TaW Sounds good. How is this achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get the system to invalidate anything but a full rectangle.

So you can't use an outline path to save time.

However it can be useful for other things. Let's look at two options :

- You can create an outline path
- You can exclude parts of a region

The simplest way to create an outline `GraphicsPath` is to **widen** a given path with a `Pen`:

```
GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
gp.AddRectangle(r0);
using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Green, 3f)) gp.Widen(pen);
```

This let's you make use of all the many options of a `Pen`, including `DashStyles`, `Alignment`, `LineJoins` etc..

An alternative way is to create it with the default `FillMode.Alternate` and simply add a smaller figure:

```
Rectangle r0 = new Rectangle(11, 11, 333, 333);
Rectangle r1 = r0;
r1.Inflate(-6, -6);
GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
gp.AddRectangle(r0);
gp.AddRectangle(r1);
```

Now you can fill the path

```
g.FillPath(Brushes.Red, gp);
```

or use it to clip the  `ClipBounds` of a `Graphics` object `g` :

```
g.SetClip(gp);
```

After this anything you draw including a `Clear` will only affect the pixels inside the outline.

When you are done you can write:

```
g.ResetClip();
```

and continue drawing on the full size of your graphics target.

Or you can use the path as the basis for a `Region`:

```
Region r = new Region(gp);
```

and restrict a `Control` to it..:

```
somecontrol.Region = r;
```

`Regions` support several **set operations** so instead of using the above outline path you could also write this with the same result:

```
Region r = new Region(r0);
r.Exclude(r1);
```

Comment: Do have a look at the updated answer: Widen is a nice and fancyful option as well for some situations!

Comment: Thanks. I will investigate tomorrow! 